# Is a local defined array valid outside its function where it is defined?

Tags: c, arrays, memory, scope, lifetime

If we define an array inside `SomeFunction` it is valid in its scope. But where is it stored actually? Local variables are usually stored on the stack but I was asking myself if the whole array stored on the stack or just the pointer to the datafield, where the data is actually stored (like calling malloc which allocates memory on the heap). Talking about the implementation in microcontrollers.

So this question leads me also to another question. If the data is stored in the Heap, is it a valid operation if the pointer will be saved to `pdata`and accessed in a different scope (`SomeOtherFunction`)? Is the data valid to use there or how do I know if the data is not valid anymore?

```
#define DATAFIELDLEN 127

static uint8_t* pdata;

static void SomeFunction()
{
    uint8_t dataField[DATAFIELDLEN] = {};

    // Write some stuff to the datafield

    pdata = dataField;  // Save pointer to the datafield
}

static void SomeOtherFunction()
{
    // Use datafield here
    for(uint8_t ii=0; ii<DATAFIELDLEN; ii++){
        // Dereference Data here
        someOperation(pdata[ii]);       // <-------- is the data valid here?
    }
}

void main() 
{
    SomeFunction();
    SomeOtherFunction();
}
```

Another possibility would be to to define the datafield in the global scope of this file as `static`. Then the data is stored in the zero initialized data and is valid in the whole file. But in the approach I presented I thought of saving some space in the RAM by not holding this datafield available all the time. Or is there another usefull practice?

Comment: Why don't you look up C11 draft standard, `6.2.4 Storage durations of objects`?

Comment: "local" is a matter of scope, not lifetime. Do not confuse that with automatic variables!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the data is not valid there.  You could make it sort of valid, but it's really dangerous.  Let me explain.

When you allocate the array in `SomeFunction()` it is allocated on the stack.  That means that once you have returned from that function, the memory will be overwritten at some point in the future as the stack is used.  You would be dereferencing a pointer into a memory area that you're not really controlling.  You might get away with it sometimes, but it is definitely undefined behavior.

On the other hand, while really, really not advised, you could mark that array as `static`.  If you did so, it will no longer be allocated on the stack and you could continue to access it when it goes out of scope.  Please be clear that I'm not recommending this as a good solution.

The proper way to make this stay valid would be to `malloc()` the memory for it and point to it with `pdata`.

Comment: Even if he would go use `malloc()`, i hope that he doesn't forget to use `free()` after it.

Comment: Of course...  Sort of thought it went without saying.

Comment: Another way in which such arrays live for application duration is if the code after the declaration enters an endless loop, maybe around a blocking syscall.  Not uncommon, but outside the scope of C.

Answer (score 1):

No, the `dataField` is local to the function `SomeFunction()`. Once the function finishes the execution, there is no existance of `dataField`.

Any means of accessing the `dataField` outside the function (saving it to a global pointer, returning the pointer and then using it in the caller) will cause invalid memory access which in turn invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

To elaborate a bit on this, quoting the `C11` standard, chapter §6.2.4, *Storage durations of objects*, (*emphasis mine*)

> The lifetime of an object is the portion of program execution during which storage is
>   guaranteed to be reserved for it. An object exists, has a constant address,33) and retains
>   its last-stored value throughout its lifetime.34) **If an object is referred to outside of its
>   lifetime, the behavior is undefined. The value of a pointer becomes indeterminate when
>   the object it points to (or just past) reaches the end of its lifetime.**

Also, for automatic local variables,

> An object whose identifier is declared with no linkage and without the storage-class
>   specifier `static` has automatic storage duration, [...] For such an object that does not have a variable length array type, its lifetime extends
>   from entry into the block with which it is associated until execution of that block ends in
>   any way.